# How can I limit exim4 processes for outgoing emails?

Tags: exim

Does anybody know how I can set a limit for exim4 processes because an application send to our smtp server 4000+ mails and crashed it. I try to add

queue_run_max=20

in /etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template, but nothing happens.

Any ideas??
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend putting this setting into /etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf and then restarting exim.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation.It seems that had effect even from  exim4.conf.template.